# Merge multiline strings in php

Tags: php, for-loop, merge, multiline, lowest-common-ancestor

I am trying to merge multi line strings. I have written the code for merging data which doesn't have "/n" character but unable to proceed with it. What I need to achieve is, comparing ancestor node with a remote node and local node and merging changes of either remote or local in ancestor line by line. Each line should be compared between `$ancestor->$remote` and `$ancestor->$local` and updated in **ancestor**.

**For example:** 3rd line is changed in remote but not local, so all changes from line 3 of `$remote` should be merged into $ancestor and same should happen with 6th line of `$local` if there is a change in line 6.

**Another Example**:

```
$ancestor = "This is a 
             normal comment"
$remtote = "This is not a 
             normal comment"
$local = "This is a 
             abnormal comment"
$expected_result = "This is not a 
             abnormal comment"
```

Comment: Can you please explain what it is doing? Pardon me if it's a silly question. I am very new to PHP.

Comment: Pardon me if I have explained it in a wrong manner. What I am trying to achieve is something like this:
$ancestor = "This is a
                      normal comment"
$local = "This is not a
               normal comment"
$remote = "This is a 
                   abnormal comment"
$expected_result = "This is not a 
                                  abnormal comment"

Comment: I misunderstood your problem.